# Advanced search with django and tastypie

Tags: django, search, tastypie

i have a question about searing with django that i can't figure out.
I have two models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    parent    = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True)
    title     = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug      = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    unique_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title          = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    category       = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='maincategory')
    subcategory    = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='subcategory')
    subsubcategory = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='subsubcategory')
```

My search query looks like this: /?categories=slug1-slug2-slug3-slug4-slug5,
so i use python to split it like this:

```
categories = request.GET.get('categories', '').split('-')
```

To achieve my goal i might have to rebuild my models, so this is where i need your help.

First i search for all the posts in the main category:

```
posts  = Post.object.filter(main_category=main_category) #Main category is the first element i categories
```

The list of categories (?categories=slug1-slug2-slug3) can both be subcategories and subsubcategories.

So how can i first filter the posts on slug2, and then filter the posts on slug3 after?

---

Whats happening with me now is that when i filter on slug2, there is no posts left to filter on slug3. So i guess i have to loop through the slugs, and then join the result after?

Comment: main_category is not Post object field. Did you mean Post.object.filter(category=main_category) ?

Comment: Yes remy_g, that was what i meant.

Comment: Other than providing category, subcategory, subsubcategory, or subsubsubsubsubcategory, it's time for you to use `django-mptt`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on django-mptt adityasdarma1, i will have a look at this!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but Q queries is the way I'd explore.

```
from django.db.models import Q

categories = request.GET.get('categories', '').split('-')
posts = Post.object.filter(
    Q(category__slug__in=categories) |
    Q(subcategory__slug__in=categories) |
    Q(subsubcategory__slug__in=categories))
```